# Camera_model segfault. Does it require a "real" camera_info not to crash?

Tags: ros, image-geometry, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a node that colors point clouds with a camera image.
My strategy is to project each point on the camera image plane, and find the corresponding pixel color.

In order to do so, I use the **image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel** object that can initialize itself directly from a sensor_msgs::camera_info message via the function **fromCameraInfo** and project points via the function **project3dToPixel**.

The current setup I have consist of a [labybug3](http://www.ptgrey.com/products/ladybug3/Ladybug3_360_video_camera.asp) camera and a tilting hokuyo LRF.
I haven't develop a proper driver for the camera, so for the moment, I am using the [camera_1394](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394) package using the following configuration:

```
<node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="ladybug" >
    <param name="guid" value="00b09d01009f01a2" />
    <param name="video_mode" value="1600x1200_mono8" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="ladybug0" />
    <param name="bayer_pattern" value="rggb" />
    <param name="auto_white_balance" value="2" />
</node>
```

As you can notice, I do not provide any calibration info, which result in uncalibrated camera_info messages. (from camera1394: *If CameraInfo calibration is not available or is incompatible with the current video_mode, uncalibrated data will be provided instead.*)

Which is indeed what I can observe with rostopic:

```
header: 
  seq: 22480
  stamp: 
    secs: 1305821789
    nsecs: 356266975
  frame_id: /ladybug0
height: 1200
width: 1600
distortion_model: ''
D: []
K: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
R: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
P: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
---
```

My problem is that I am able to initialize my camera model using those camera_info messages, but my program keeps crashing on the call to **project3dToPixel**.

Code:

```
cv::Point2d pixel;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_xyz;
[...]
for(int i = 0 ; i < (int) cloud_xyz.size(); i++)
{
     if (isnan (cloud_xyz.points[i].x) || isnan (cloud_xyz.points[i].y) || isnan (cloud_xyz.points[i].z))
            continue;
     ROS_INFO("point with coordinates %f, %f, %f", cloud_xyz.points[i].x, cloud_xyz.points[i].y, cloud_xyz.points[i].z);
     ROS_INFO("A");
     cv::Point3d point(cloud_xyz.points[i].x, cloud_xyz.points[i].y, cloud_xyz.points[i].z);
     ROS_INFO("B");
     pixel = cam_model.project3dToPixel(point);
```

Trace:

```
[ INFO] [1305820636.985045709]: point with coordinates 0.245843, -6.119996, 0.848742
[ INFO] [1305820636.985082376]: A
[ INFO] [1305820636.985117506]: B
Segmentation fault
```

I had a look inside [image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel's documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html) but I can't find any information on the case where the camera_info messages are 0.

My best guess so far is that the on calibrated camera_info message triggers the segfault at runtime.
Does anyone has experience with this issue?

Thanks for your help

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9999/camera_model-segfault.-does-it-require-a-%22real%22-camera_info-not-to-crash?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-20**:
You will have to reproduce the segfault to get the core. If you've done that, and it still doesn't show up, then I'm not sure. It should be there.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-19**:
I followed your method but I haven't any "core" folder or file in my ~/.ros folder. Any idea?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-19**:
actually see this post here if you just want the stack trace without having to modify anything: http://answers.ros.org/question/910/is-there-functionality-built-into-ros-to-get-nodes

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-19**:
Use GDB ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB ) , when it starts type "run" if necessary and when it crashes, type "bt". If you do get a stacktrace, it would be good to attach to any ticket you create.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-19**:
Noob question: any tool you advise for this?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-19**:
I don't know off hand, but might be able to tell you with a stacktrace.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-07-09**:
Hi. Have you made any progress with the ladybug? I'm trying to setup mine and I'd gladly learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should file a ticket for this. The camera info message you see represents an uncalibrated camera, but is still a valid camera_info message. PinholeCameraModel should probably ROS_WARN or something when you attempt to make it with an uncalibrated or otherwise invalid camera_info message instead of segfaulting when it tries to apply that camera_info message.

On another note, you will have to provide a valid calibration in order for the PinholeCameraModel to use when projecting points to pixels.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-19**:
Ah.. then that fromcamerainfo should most likely return false in your case :). Also, do post back with a link to the relevant ticket.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-19**:
thx for this info, ill post the ticket. Also fromcamerainfo returns a bool that was true in my case.